# How auto add the website link in Sitelinks Searchbox

Tags: javascript, json

In my website i have subdomain, example it.mywebsite.com es.mywebsite.com etc. and i want to add 1 code for all my subwebsites, is posible to add the website link in automatic?

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
   {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "url": "https://mywebsite.com/",
      "potentialAction": {
         "@type": "SearchAction",
         "target": "https://mywebsite.com/s/{search_term_string}",
         "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things, you're trying to set up a **[Google SiteLinks searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox)**. According to **[this post](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/SOuA4dD1J6c/vC4uUF5gEYIJ)**,

> Unfortunately, Google currently does not support the sitelinks search box feature for subdomains or subfolders.

So no, it is not possible to set up different SiteLinks searchboxes for subdomains.